# can't access network share (windows accessing raspberry pi)

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, samba

can't access network share (windows accessing raspberry pi)

I wrote a bootable Pi OS onto a Micro-SD card for my raspberry pi, with the raspberry pi imager download for windows https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/

[image]

and a usb sd card reader..

And that worked.

I put the Micro-SD card in the Pi, and the OS started.

I got SSH started.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable ssh
$ sudo systemctl start ssh
```

And `sudo systemctl status ssh` shows it.

To SSH in, I did `sudo passwd pi` and set a password for that user. From Windows cygwin I did SSH pi@192.168.0.20 and I've SSHd in as user 'pi' and made another user too from the pi, with the `adduser` command.  SSH is fine.  From Windows, I can transfer files to and from the Pi with FileZilla as that supports the SSH form of FTP -SFTP.

I want to transfer files fairly seamlessly between Windows and the Pi, and I want to map a network drive.. So i'm trying to set up SAMBA on the Pi.

From what I understand ,  Pi OS is debian based but i've been looking at Pi specific websites for instructions..

Looking at this https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/samba-file-server  for the commands to get SAMBA running

I did `sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin`

and  `sudo systemctl start nmbd`

and I tried `sudo systemctl status smbd.service` and `sudo systemctl status nmbd`  and it seems to be running.

And once SAMBA ran, I tried \192.168.0.20 and it opened an explorer window up and showed the network printer.

So I looked into sharing a directory from the pi.

I tried what it said here about adding this to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[share]
Comment = Pi shared folder
Path = /share
Browseable = yes
Writeable = Yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
Public = yes
Guest ok = yes
```

I used that though changed the directory to share.

I changed it to  PATH = ~/share

and I made a directory ~/share and did chmod 777 on it, or as that link https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/  suggested, 1777.  Though I used chmod to do set the permission and that link used mkdir to both create and set permission.

I did `sudo systemctl restart smbd.service` after editing that samba configuration file.

The directory appears when I do \192.168.0.20 , i.e. the directory shows as an icon, but I get an error  when I double click that directory/folder, it says  "Windows cannot access \192.168.0.20/share    Check the spelling of the name"

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the full path and not use ~/

So,  `/home/pi/blah`  and not `~/blah`

changing to full path,  in the samba configuration file, so using `/home/pi/blah`  worked.

```
[share]
Comment = Pi shared folder
Path = /home/pi/share
Browseable = yes
Writeable = Yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
Public = yes
Guest ok = yes
```

(i.e. not Path = ~/share )

Comment: (this solution to my question is the answer.. but I will accept after 2 days when the system lets me)